# toast message does not show in list view

Tags: android, android-layout

in my app in a list view i list all the videos thumb nail with description in a list view. for list view module i get code from `http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/custom-arrayadapter-with-with-different.html`.

from the link i remove code listing "sunday,monday" and it related. instead that i code for listing video thumb nail as follows. **if i touch the list(screen) no toast message is displayed after change the code.** but in the original code toast message is displayed. please help me.
my code

```
public class AndroidList extends ListActivity {

private final static Uri MEDIA_EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
private final static String _ID = MediaStore.Video.Media._ID;
private final static String MEDIA_DATA = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA;
private Cursor _cursor;
private int _columnIndex;
private Uri _contentUri;
private String[] _videosId;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    _contentUri = MEDIA_EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    initVideosId();
    setListAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(AndroidList.this, R.layout.row,_videosId));

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Log.e("video", "called");
    String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private void initVideosId() {
    try {
        String[] proj = { _ID };
        _cursor = managedQuery(_contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int count = _cursor.getCount();
        _columnIndex = _cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID);
        _videosId = new String[count];
        _cursor.moveToFirst();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int id = _cursor.getInt(_columnIndex);
            _videosId[i] = String.valueOf(id);
            _cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("video", ex.getMessage().toString());
    }

}

public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        }
        TextView textfilePath = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.FilePath);
        textfilePath.setText(_videosId[position]);
        ImageView imageThumbnail = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.Thumbnail);

        Bitmap bmThumbnail;
        int ids;
        ids = Integer.parseInt(_videosId[position]);
        bmThumbnail = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(), ids,MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
        imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);

        return row;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: no i completely remove that String[] dayofweek . instead of i place code for getting video thumb nail. as in my question. please check it and help me.

Comment: are u getting the images from sd card

Comment: i am getting video thumb nail from sdcard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the value of `selection` when you show the toast? Try to assign an hard-coded value to make sure it works.

Comment: no toast message is shown and  the onListItemClick method is not called after change my code. in the original code it shows sunday ,monday .... please help me.

Comment: You have to initialize _videosId *before* setting the list adapter. Can you post the code where you do that?

Comment: please check my edited question. i paste full coding.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put "this" in your toast, try to put something like : getApplicationContext() or getBaseContext() .